# Node js don't deliver css and js to tablet

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I'm using a node js server as a webserver to deliver my webapp.
At the moment the server runs locally on my machine. If I call `localhost:port` or `IP:Port` in the browser it works fine. But if I call `IP:port` from my tablet to test it, it looks like the CSS and Javascript are not loaded. Just the Bootstrap thins looks fine but my own CSS and js are not loaded.

This is the app.js of the node js server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server_connection = require('./server_connection/server_connection.js');
const updateDB = require('./db_operations/updateDB.js')
const cronjobs = require('./cron_jobs/dbUpdateJob.js')
const path = require('path');
const filterController = require('./filter/filterController.js');

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/../Client'));

app.listen(server_connection.port, () => {
    console.log('Server started on port ' + server_connection.port);
    //do stuff
});

//load the index.html from the server
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '../Client/index.html'));
});
```

This is the folder structure:

```
Server/
   app.js
Client/
   index.html
   css/
     style.css
   scripts/
     multimple files
```

Comment: If you havent hosted the nodejs app on a public server, your tablet is not going to be resolve your machine's IP, try using a tool like ngrok see here https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrok it will proxy your app from your machine to a publicly accessible address

Comment: ok this is not bad but still the problem: If I call now on the desktop: `http://link.ngrok.io` it works correct but if I call `httpS://link.ngrok.io` it looks like on the tablet with the missing CSS and JS. On the tablet it doesn't matter if `http` or `https`.

Also on desktop version with `https` I get a lot of this error messages:
`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://1234.ngrok.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://localhost:3000/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: ooh so when using `https`  in the browser, content requested over `http` are ignored thats probably why.... and also it seems like you hard coded the value for the stylesheet as `http://localhost:3000/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css` instead of `/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css` so it just picks the value of whatever host is serving it